# TFS Git Template XAML,how to label sources on build?

Tags: git, tfs, label, tfsbuild

I am using TFS Git Template for XAML build but there is no option to label sources on build.How can i do that?
Below is the build template GitTemplate12.xaml where i cannot find the label sources

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't have labels. It has tags. The old XAML build process template for Git is limited and does not support creating tags during the build.

Comment: How to due it using custom scripts?Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Add a tag, push the tag to the repo. I've never done that with XAML build before so I can't rate the level of difficulty.

Comment: how can i add a tag?

Comment: Using [git tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) command to add tag, then push to remote repository (git push)